# Map function: anonymous function vs function expression

Tags: javascript

Why does passing an anonymous function into the `map` function work, but attempting to pass a function expression throws an error?

```
arr = [2,4,6,8];

items = arr.map(function(x) {
  return Math.pow(x, 2);
});

console.log(items);  // Returns [4, 16, 36, 64]

squareIt = function(x) {
  return Math.pow(x, 2);
}

otherItems = arr.map(squareIt(x));

console.log(otherItems);  // Returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the function itself

```
arr.map( squareIt );
```

if you use `squareIt(x)` instead, you call directly the function and pass as argument its return value.

In your case you got an additional error because `x` is not defined when you call the function

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function works fine, however when you use `()` in the pass argument, it invokes the function immediately:

```
otherItems = arr.map(squareIt(x)); <---Invoked immediately!
```

The correct way would be to use an anonymous function and call your function with the arguments:

```
otherItems = arr.map(function() {
    squareIt(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because function expression are executed  immediately. So when it tries to invoke SquareIt(X), it can not find X and hence you get the exception `"Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"`. Try defining X  before the call, say `x = 4;`

you will then get an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: 16 is not a function
```

because the Map function expects a function as an argument, not an integer.

When you pass function with out `()` , you are kind of passing a callback.